# How to .params use in finding DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have:

```
var tag = this.params['tag'];
```

How to use it in:

```
$('tag')
```

?

Comment: There is not enough information to answer your question properly. Please be more specific. If you want to use the variable `tag`, then just pass it to jQuery: `$(tag)`. That's how you pass variables to functions. I encourage you to read a good JavaScript tutorial, such as http://eloquentjavascript.net/.

Comment: Please provide more code and a more detailed description of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the params in `this.params['tag'];` ?

It's not a native property.

it is probably your type/object

so you can use it underjQuery with :

```
$('tag')[0].params['tag'] //better
```

or

```
$('tag').prop('params').tag //not recommanded
```

Comment: I'm very convinced that `this` does not refer to a DOM element.

Comment: @Bergi we can use prop also on regular object. `var t={"a":{k:1},"b":2};

alert($(t).prop('a')['k'])//alerts 1.` http://jsbin.com/iqoyuz/1/edit

Comment: OK, we can - but we don't do it…

Comment: @Bergi That's another thing. he wanted to use it under $() wrapper so I showed him how. that's all.

Comment: He's a newbie. Even if we'd say that he *can* do it, we would need to advise against using it and tell him that what he *wants* was the wrong tool.

Comment: @Bergi that's why I supplied 2 solutions. I will clarify it.